# String variable preventing class data from printing

Tags: python, class

Whenever I try this:

```
x = input(foo)
showstat(x)

def showstat(y):
    print(y.thing)
```

It comes back as an error

> 'str' object has no attribute 'thing'

but I don't know how to change it's data type in order to make it function properly.

I just need to figure out how to make it read as:

```
print(foo.thing)
```

rather than the error:

```
print("foo".thing)
```

Comment: A big part of programming is diagnosing errors.  If you're asking about an error, you _need_ to include the error.

Comment: You say you know why it doesn't work, but your final question doesn't sound like you understand what the error shows.

Comment: Why would `x` have a `thing` attribute? What kind of object were you expecting it to be?

Comment: On the rest of the program, I have it print out the names of some of the class items, the input is to determine which of them should have their attrabutes displayed, the input BEING an item in the class you can find the full code here: https://pythonroom.com/python/#-LQdFPFdnqslzL9glWoP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to evaluate the input as a python expression so you can retrieve the variable with the name entered. Is this correct?

If so you can use

```
eval(x)
```

though safer would be something like

```
locals()[x]
```

I would personally do this to your input, not as part of the function, but it depends on exactly what else you're trying to do.

Comment: @BeardedPancake keep [this](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) in mind. You should not find yourself in a position where you need to do either of these things

Comment: it's a momentary solution, and should it continue to work for the rest of the program, then so be it.